# Can I allow dynamic loading of JS modules from the client side?

Tags: javascript

In my web app I want to give users the ability to author their own modules for use in the app. These are ideally written in JS on the client side.

However, I'm having trouble allowing for classes created on the client side to be accessed by the app. Originally I wanted some kind of module import, but dynamic imports still require a path, which isn't accessible by the browser for security reasons. Just doing a straight import of the JS into a script tag pollutes the global namespace, which isn't ideal either.

Is there some sensible way to do this? I would ideally want to import the class, e.g.

```
// MyClass.js, on the client side
export default class MyClass {
    myPrint() {
        console.log('ya blew it');
    }
}
```

And then in App.js:

```
import(somehow_get_this_path).then((MyClass) => { etc});
```

Is getting that path possible? The current namespace-polluting method uses a select file dialog but doesn't allow me to tell import what path it has. All you get is a blob. I'm pretty new to this stuff so apologies if this question is dumb.

edit: I've tried getting an object URL using CreateObjectURL, which gives the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'blob:null/d651a896-d568-437f-86d0-72ebcee7bc56'
```

Comment: There is _"some"_ browser support for [dynamic imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import#Dynamic_Imports), as long as you don't need IE or Edge coverage

Comment: @Phil yeah I've been trying that, but you need to specify a path for the file, right? Am I correct in saying I can't do that in the app since the browser can't know what the user's filesystem is like? It can get the name but not the absolute path.

Comment: The path needs to refer to a resource available to the system running the code. So if it's running in a browser, it should be a URL (relative, absolute, whatever).

Answer (score 2):

if you are using webpack as a bundler then use can use [magic comments](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#magic-comments) to lazy load the components.

or else you can use dynamic imports.

```
 import('path_to_my_class').then(MyClass => {
    // Do something with MyClass
 });
```

Edited 1:-

You can use this code to get a working local URL for the uploaded js file. try using this

```
const path = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(file);
console.log('path', path);
```

Edited 2:-

Alternatively, you can create your own object at a global level and wrap the file using an anonymous function (creating closure) such that it won't pollute the global namespace.

```
// you can add other methods to it according to your use case.
window.MyPlugins =  {
  plugins: [],
  registerPlugin: function (plugin){
    this.plugins.push(plugin);
  }
}
```

```js
// MyFirstPlugin.js

// you can inject this code via creating a script tag.

(function(w){ //closure
  function MyFirstPlugin() {
    this.myPrint = function (){
       console.log('ya blew it');
    }
  }
  w.MyPlugins.registerPlugin(new MyFirstPlugin());
})(window)
```

```
// get the reference to the plugin in some other file
 window.MyPlugins.plugins
```

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, have edited the question - I don't know how to get the path to their class. At the moment I'm allowing the user to select a file using a dialog, but that doesn't give you a path so import isn't usable.

Comment: thanks, but that gives the error:  Error: Cannot find module 'blob:null/d651a896-d568-437f-86d0-72ebcee7bc56'

I've updated my question

Comment: @KingCoyote just wanted to know the user can upload any js file? if so then how do you validate that the file doesn’t have any bad/hackable code? and you need to make sure that the uploaded file has code which is transpiled in ES5.

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure how that would be handled. It does seem extremely unsafe, but the spec is a bit vague so maybe it's not what they meant. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @KingCoyote okay, I have updated my answer. you can try that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Read file and use eval

```html
 <script>
 function importJS(event) {
   var input = event.target;
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(){
      eval(reader.result);
      input.value='';
   };
   reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
 };
</script>

Select a *.js file and execute
<br>
<br>
<input type="file" onchange="importJS(event);">
```